# Vuejs get form data from array

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a form which is showing multiple input based on database data and I need to get each input value when I submit my form.

## Code

```
<form ref="form" :model="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div
        class="col-md-6"
        v-for="(field, index) in fields"
        :key="index"
        >
        <input
            class="form-control"
            v-model="form.field"
            :placeholder="field.title"
        />
        </div>
    </div>
    <vs-button
        class="mt-3"
        @click="onSubmit"
        native-type="submit"
        gradient
    >
        Generate
    </vs-button>
</form>


data() {
    return {
      fields: [],
      form: {
        field: [],
      },
    };
},
```

## Issue

My issue is that currently when I fill 1 input others get the same value, I need to fill each input individually.

## Screenshots

[image: one]

[image: two]

**Any idea?**

Comment: have you tried field[index]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using your `v-model` pointing to `form.field`, try to use `v-model="form.field[index]"`